# ggplot proportion bar using 2 columns and base on the a row name R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I Have created the following table and I'm trying to create a proportion bar plot that will visualize out of the 100% what is the proportion of n1 and n2.

my table is as follows :

```
type            n1            n2           total
<chr>          <int>         <int>         <int>
a              4278           903          5181
b              4004           286          4290
c              4268           304          4572
d              4645           105          4750
e              5068           148          5216
f              4338           9            4347
```

Then what I would like to have is something like a barplot that visualize the proportion of each type in the x axis, with y axis as a bar that divides the 100% to the proportions of n1 and n2

Couldn't find anywhere how to take the proportion with this way, i did tried to play with position=fill but failed.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code you tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that your data is in the wide format instead of the long format. If you reshape your data, plotting it is pretty easy.

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
  type = letters[1:6],
  n1 = c(4278, 4004, 4268, 4645, 5068, 4338),
  n2 = c(903, 286, 304, 105, 148, 9)
)

# Reshaping data
dat <- tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, c(n1, n2))

ggplot(dat, aes(type, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = 'fill')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In essence it is the solution provided by teunbrand just adding the percent labels.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("n"),
    names_to = "n",
    values_to = "value"
  )%>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(per= prop.table(value) * 100)


  ggplot(df1, aes(x=type, y=per, fill = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(per,1),"%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3)
```

[image]
data:

```
df <- tribble(
~type, ~n1, ~n2, ~total, 
"a", 4278, 903, 5181, 
"b", 4004, 286, 4290, 
"c", 4268, 304, 4572, 
"d", 4645, 105, 4750, 
"e", 5068, 148, 5216, 
"f", 4338, 9, 4347)
```